# Formation of Probability Density function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, density-function

**Question:**

> A stone is thrown into a circular pond of radius 1 meter. Suppose the stone falls uniformly at random on the area of the pond. Find the expected distance of the stone from the center of the pond.

I have tried to solve this by creating a probability density function and the finding the expected value of $X^2+Y^2$. I defined 2 uniform random variables $X$ and $Y$ in $[-1,1]$ and found that the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ is

$$\frac14\quad,-1<x<1,-1<y<1;\quad 0\quad,\text{ otherwise }$$

After this, I found the expected value of $X^2+Y^2$ which came out to be $\frac23$ and seems to be the right answer. But my question is if my joint PDF is right to solve this question. It looks like $X$ and $Y$ are dependent here. Also the pond cannot be more than $1$ meter in radius but my function $X^2+Y^2$ takes value $2$ when $X=1,Y=1$.

Comment: The pond is circular so $(1,1)$ is not one of its points. The joint PDF for $(X,Y)$ is indeed constant but takes value $\frac1{\pi}$. You are asked to find the expectation of $R:=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$. Further it is more handsome to find a PDF for $R$ and apply $\mathbb ER=\int rf_R(r)dr$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @drhab Thank you so much. I got the answer